# How to exclude code coverage using UI at project Level?

Tags: sonarqube

I noticed my basedir in MSBUILD is `C:\blah.git\Bah\Source\**` which has several different directories that is runs code coverage on.

My example is:

```
C:\blah.git\Blah\Source\Core
C:\blah.git\Blah\Source\Logo
C:\blah.git\Blah\Source\Files
C:\blah.git\Blah\Source\MoreStuff
```

It runs code coverage on each one of those areas so I cannot use the expression `**/MoreStuff/**` 
to exclude MoreStuff from the codecoverage.  As that expresssion would look for:
`C:\blah.git\Blah\Source\MoreStuff\**\MoreStuff\**`.

I tried to use ..\MoreStuff** but that does not work.

Any suggestion on the syntax to exclude MoreStuff?

Comment: If you have *.csproj file inside MoreStuff catalog then this is impossible, as this is a root of your project. Nasty trick would be to mark MoreStuff catalog as test project - after that sonar will ignore it in coverage results. You could go to Administration > General Settings > Scanner for MSBuild and set test project pattern (but this is deprecated), or use sonar.msbuild.testProjectPattern during the scan.

Comment: So in .csproj of MoreStuff add <SonarQubeTestProject>true</SonarQubeTestProject>